# Count occurrences of elements for a set of intervals in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have data like this

| Number | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1.5 | X |
| 2.4 | X |
| 3.1 | Y |
| 3.2 | Y |

My desired output is

| ID | 1 < x < 2 | 2 < x < 3 | 3 < x < 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Y | 0 | 0 | 2 |

What would be an efficient approach to creating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a column with `cut` and then use `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(grp = cut(Number, breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
      labels = c("1<x<2", "2<x<3", "3<x<4"))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from= Number,
         values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  ID    `1<x<2` `2<x<3` `3<x<4`
  <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 X           1       1       0
2 Y           0       0       2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Number = c(1.5, 2.4, 3.1, 3.2), ID = c("X", "X", 
"Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```